# How to print all of the file data

Tags: python, file

Im trying to print all of the file data but at first it doesnt show anything... Why? If i run it few times it shows me the data without the first input...

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self):

        self.add = open("user_data.txt", "a")
        self.add.write("data")

    def add_data(self, user_name, password):

        self.add.write(user_name)
        self.add.write(",")
        self.add.write(password)
        self.add.write(";")
        self.read = open("user_data.txt", "r")

    def show_file(self):

        print self.read.read()


d = Data()
d.add_data("asdv", "safvas")
d.show_file()
```

Comment: You have that same file open already, thanks to `self.add`. Close it first.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your file after writing to it. Also, you should open your file for reading in the show_file() method:

```
 class Data:

def __init__(self):

    self.add = open("user_data.txt", "a")
    self.add.write("data")
    self.add.close()

def add_data(self, user_name, password):
    self.add = open('user_data.txt', 'a')
    self.add.write(user_name)
    self.add.write(",")
    self.add.write(password)
    self.add.write(";")
    self.add.close()

def show_file(self):
    self.read = open("user_data.txt", "r")
    print self.read.read()


d = Data()
d.add_data("asdv", "safvas")
d.show_file()
```

Comment: shouldnt i open the file each use?